# How can I use the "Attribute Sample Texture" in new Builds 3.0?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have tried to substitute the (no longer available) GeoNode "Attribute sample Texture" with the Image Texture directly connected to "Density-Factor" of the DPOF node.  However, it does not seem to work at all.  I even tried with Color-ramp and Math "Round" to see if I could get something out of it, but nothing.
The image is a simple B/W draw.
[image]

Comment: I don't believe this question should be closed, perhaps change the title, but the question is still legit.

Comment: Ok.  question edited.

Comment: What you are trying should work if you remove the _Round_ node.  What happens if you do that?  Can you provide a simple example blend file with the image packed in it and a screenshot of what the result in 2.93 was? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: I looks like there is a problem with the uploader. Could not Up the .Blend. Sorry.
Anyway,  I have tried to connect directly the texture to the DPOF node, and nothing as well.  The position and rounding are just to assure that the texture will stay with clear bounds and be correctly positioned.

Comment: I vote to close this question because it cannot be answered satisfactorily with the available information, and has not been added to since it was created.